# c# uwp listview finished loading items

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

In C# UWP what event is fired when all items in listview are loaded and rendering is done?

I need to make some calculations that will be executed after loading is finished.

Comment: Do you use async operations to populate the data in the `ListView`?

Comment: There isn't a single specific event for when *all* rendering is done - or in the case of a ListView, when all items in view are rendered. Keep in mind rendering is also virtualized so not all of you items may be rendered off the bat.

Answer (score -2):

Is [FrameworkElement.Loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_Loaded) what you're looking for?